# Why is PHP's ZipArchive faster than using unzip via exec()?

Tags: php, linux, unzip, php-ziparchive

I made three ZIP files (one with no compression settings, one with minimal compression and one with maximum compression)

I then had my script unzip each one, and timed it. First I did it with `ZipArchive`, then with `exec('unzip')`

Every time, it was faster using `ZipArchive` then `exec('unzip')`

I thought that surely a native program would be faster than a library? Are there some switches I could use with `exec('unzip')` (that would make it similar to `ZipArchive`) to make it as fast?

Comment: Probably the process-creation penalty. Starting a new process, such as via exec, is always very slow. Try it with a very large, very complex archive, and the native program should catch up.